# Which HTTP method to use when no data is transfered, just to execute code in an endpoint?

Tags: python, flask, httprequest, openapi

I build an  Flask API endpoint which when called will execute an action to process some data (the data are not send but come from the database). The result of the method(action) called is to update some fields in some database objects based on calculations performed on the objects themselves.

Initially from what I found most people use POST requests, but post request is mainly designed for sending data in order to create a resource and in these cases no such thing takes place.

I looked at all the possible [HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and no one fits the bill of just asynchronously executing some code in the server without sending and returning any data.

Am I missing something, should I simply use `POST` or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATCH` seems to be the correct method for your use case since you're updating some fields of a resource, although `POST` should also be fine.

You can use 204 status code (which means api was successfully executed but there's no content to send) if you're updating the fields before api return. Refer this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204

But if you're updating the fields async after api return, you should send 202 status code (which means request was accepted but not yet processed): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here. I'm not entirely sure how this server is set up but whichever works best for you.

1. Use POST, and the data transferred is the name of the function being run. This is useful because you could use one server to execute multiple functions and call them through POST data. Otherwise, a data-less POST request could still be used to run a function, and your server could just detect any POST request.
2. Use HEAD, this only works if your server is only accessed to execute this function. Your server could detect any HEAD request, and run the function on a connection.

HEAD would be a little finicky here, and I would personally recommend POST. With POST you could also send some sort of Key with the request to set up some security on your server, and the aforementioned feature of using multiple functions on one server (e.x. get methods, access methods, parse functions, etc.). Very expandable.

Answer (score 0):

The "resource" you are creating it a request to execute some code.

Comment: Hi, maybe I am tired but there might be a typo in the comment I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Think of it the POST request as creating a "virtual" resource. Whether or not anything truly gets created, the server immediately acts on the request and executes the code. (If you want, you could provide an endpoint to see what requests  have been created, what their status is, what the result was, etc. If none of this is done, though, the original "resource" doesn't actually need to be realized; the server can simply act immediately on the request.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use PUT, as you are requesting the creation of some resource (ie the thing that runs your request).